App that I'm running with wine knows that it's running on wine. Can I somehow trick it so it thinks that it runs regular windows?
So I was trying to play MTA San Andreas with Wine, but when I tried to join my favourite server, I got an error message saying "Wine emulation is not allowed on this server" or something like that. Can I make the game think that it's running on windows, and not through wine so I can get rid of this message and join the server?
Also sorry for my (possibly) bad english

Please do not ask yes/no questions. Oh and of course the answer is no. If it was yes  everyone would be using that. WINE can not use are proprietary parts of Windows. If you want to use those servers play the game in a way it is intended: use Windows OS in dual boot or inside a VBox or VMWare player.

Check with https://www.winehq.org. Not all Windows programs are available through wine. This is not a Ubuntu problem, this is a wine problem.
